# jquery dynamically create table from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to create a table from an array. The array is formatted like the following:

```
[
  {
    header: 'ID',
    values: [1, 2]
  },
  {
    header: 'First Name',
    values: ['John', 'Jayne']
  },
  {
    header: 'Last Name',
    value: ['Doe', 'Doe']
  }
]
```

I've been successful in creating the headers for the table but a bit stumped on where or how to approach the rendering from the body in such a fashion from this array.

```js
const exampleArray = [
  {
    header: 'ID',
    values: [1, 2]
  },
  {
    header: 'First Name',
    values: ['John', 'Jayne']
  },
  {
    header: 'Last Name',
    values: ['Doe', 'Doe']
  }
];

const header = $('#results thead tr');
const body = $('#results tbody');

exampleArray.forEach((row) => {
  header.append(
    $(`<th>${row.header}</th>`)
  );
});
```

```html
<table id="results">
<thead>
<tr>
  <!-- HEADERS -->
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm unsure if this is the best kind of approach to take or whether it's worth mapping the result set into something more mutable before trying to render the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate each value item of the array and append it to each column:

```js
const exampleArray = [{
    header: 'ID',
    values: [1, 2]
  },
  {
    header: 'First Name',
    values: ['John', 'Jayne']
  },
  {
    header: 'Last Name',
    values: ['Doe', 'Doe']
  }
];

const header = $('#results thead tr');
const body = $('#results tbody');

exampleArray.forEach((row) => {
  header.append(
    $(`<th>${row.header}</th>`)
  );
});


// This does the magic

// Iterate up to the values length (row length)
for (var i = 0; i < exampleArray[0].values.length; i++) {
  // Create new row
  body.append("<tr id='row-" + i + "'></tr>");
  // Iterate all items (columns)
  exampleArray.forEach((column) => {
    // Append value to the row
    $("#row-" + i).append("<td>" + column.values[i] + "</td>");
  });
}
```

```html
<table id="results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- HEADERS -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call the elements in `exampleArray` rows, while they're in fact columns. This might be where the confusion arises from. See the snippet below for a working example.

```js
const exampleArray = [
  {
    header: 'ID',
    values: [1, 2]
  },
  {
    header: 'First Name',
    values: ['John', 'Jayne']
  },
  {
    header: 'Last Name',
    values: ['Doe', 'Doe']
  }
];

const header = $('#results thead tr');
const body = $('#results tbody');

exampleArray.forEach((column) => {
  header.append(
    $(`<th>${column.header}</th>`)
  );
});

// Compute the number of rows in the array
const nRows = exampleArray[0].values.length;

for (let i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
  // row contains all cells in a row
  let row = $("<tr/>");
  // Loop over the columns
  exampleArray.forEach((column) => {
    // For each column, we add the i-th value, since we're building the i-th row
    row.append(`<td>${column.values[i]}</td>`);
  });
  // Add the row to the table body
  body.append(row);
}
```

```html
<table id="results">
<thead>
<tr>
  <!-- HEADERS -->
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate from `0` to the length of the `values` property of the first item, and use a nested loop to get the item at that index of each individual item:

```js
const tableData = [{
    header: 'ID',
    values: [1, 2]
  },
  {
    header: 'First Name',
    values: ['John', 'Jayne']
  },
  {
    header: 'Last Name',
    values: ['Doe', 'Doe']
  }
]

const header = $('#results thead tr');
const body = $('#results tbody');

tableData.forEach((row) => {
  header.append(
    $(`<th>${row.header}</th>`)
  );
});

for (let i = 0; i < tableData[0].values.length; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  tableData.forEach(f => $(row).append(`<td>${f.values[i]}</td>`));
  body.append(row);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results">
  <thead>
    <tr id="headers">
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="b">

  </tbody>
</table>
```